# My Visual Studio 2012 environment font is now Italicized / I am unable to change the font of my application

Tags: visual-studio-2012, italics

I just noticed that not only is my application font now completely italicized, but also much of my VS2012 is too. I went to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors, and hit "Use Defaults" with no success.

I've set my entire application's MainWindow to use Sego UI with "Normal" FontStyle, but everything is in italics. This is annoying and weird.

Anyone else have this issue and found a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the WPF font cache is corrupted.  Reboot your machine.

Comment: @HansPassant -- great advice. Stopped the WPF & Windows Font Cache services, deleted the cache files and rebooted. Please post your comment as an answer if you'd like the points :)

Comment: You know a lot more about than I do, never had this problem myself.  Be sure to explain what you did in your own post and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @HansPassant for the advice regarding the font cache.

What I did was:

1. Stopped WPF Font Cache services
2. Deleted all the font cache "log" files from the locations listed in the Service list
3. Rebooted.

I am not sure exactly what caused this as I try to install some new fonts but realized IT hadn't given me permission to the folder, but I believe this strange issue arose from the last Windows update.

As it turns out, stopping the WPF font cache services can also mitigate the "glitchiness" of Visual Studio that some people experience. Hope this helps others :)

Answer (score -1):

**Example for changing regular `consolas` font to `italic` font.**

Close all applications and Visual Studio. Go to `C:\windows\fonts\consolas\`  and remove `regular` font.

Restart Visual Studio. You will see text editor italic fonts.

Comment: this achieves the opposite of the problem.